how to authenticate account when login by sms otp with firebase using java spring boot
I want to authenticate my account by sms otp with firebase using java spring boot, I have read many sources of documents but still have not found the answer, please someone guide me, thank you very much <3
I tried searching but no one gave instructions or suggestions for using with java spring boot
